# Custom video player doesnt play

Tags: video, web, playback

I am building a website for a project of mine and i want to embed a video clip which will be delivered from server with subtitles that can be turned on/off during playback.

I used this code but nothing happens. The video player does shows up but it doesn't play anything. any tips?

```
    <div class="grid-50 tablett-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 video">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_8">

    <video id="video" controls>
    <source src="files/Advert.avi" type="video">
    <track label="English" kind="captions" srclang="en" src="/files/Advert.xml">
    </track>
    </source>
    </video>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [format supported by HTML5 video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) rather than AVI. To cover most browsers with a single video format use MP4 with h.264 video and MP3 or AAC audio.